# What is expected well pressure wide open no pressure tank

Tags: well

I got 30psi wide open.  There is no pressure tank yet.

[image: well output, no pressure tank yet]

Comment: "wide open" would be 0 PSI, measured at the point where it was "wide open." You have the restriction of whatever valves and pipe/hose are between the location of the pressure gauge and the exit point of the water. There is no "expected pressure" for this situation as your "pressure-tankless" (without a fancy and more expensive controller, which still want at least a small pressure tank) setup is uncommon. Pressure reading would depend on ALL the specifics of the pump, the pipe from the pump, the water level in the well, the fittings, pipe, and hose after the gauge, etc.

Comment: I know you are supposed to refrain from thank you posts, but thank you for all the help!

Comment: @House DIY you can up vote the comment so ecnerwal gets credit for a good comment or answer (this should have been an answer).+